# Join strings split with the python [::n] method into one string as they were before in one line

Tags: python, python-3.x

If you split a string like `foobar` with something like `[::3], [1::3], [2::3]` it will give you `['fb','oa','or']`. I needed to then be able to rejoin that into `foobar` and I got given a challenge to make it in one line. This is my solution:

```
split_join = lambda t:''.join(''.join([s.ljust(len(max(t,key=len))) for s in t])[i::len(max(t,key=len))] for i in range(len(max(t,key=len)))).replace(' ','')
```

and I was wondering if there was any neater or shorter way to make this.

EDIT: I also want it to be able to deal with strings of uneven lengths

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in order to make this even remotely readable, let's convert it to a function and save intermediate results (especially the reused ones) to variables:

```
def split_join6(table):
    cols = max(map(len, table))
    justified = ''.join([col.ljust(cols) for col in table])
    y = ''.join(justified[i::cols] for i in range(cols))
    return y.replace(' ','')
```

Now, what you seem to want is similar to the [`roundrobin` recipe from `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

> ```
> from itertools import cycle, islice
>
> def roundrobin(*iterables):
>     "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
>     # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
>     num_active = len(iterables)
>     nexts = cycle(iter(it).__next__ for it in iterables)
>     while num_active:
>         try:
>             for next in nexts:
>                 yield next()
>         except StopIteration:
>             # Remove the iterator we just exhausted from the cycle.
>             num_active -= 1
>             nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, num_active))
> ```

```
x = ['fb','oa','or']
print("".join(roundrobin(*x))
# foobar
```

Note that making things into one-liners can only get you so far. It does sometimes help you to learn some new concepts in a language, but quite often it makes your code unreadable. In Python you should keep your lines to 80 or 120 characters (as per Python's official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)). Anything that does not fit into that is probably too complicated to understand again, even a month later.

That being said, here is a shorter one-liner, albeit with one needed import:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

f = lambda x: "".join(map(lambda t: "".join(filter(None, t)), zip_longest(*x)))

f(['fb','oa','or'])
# 'foobar'
```

The `zip_longest` and `filter(None, ...)` are only needed in case not all parts are the same length. Otherwise (which is at least true for `"foobar"`) it would just be:

```
f = lambda x: "".join(map("".join, zip(*x)))
```

Both use the well-known trick of doing `zip(*iterable)` to transpose an iterable of iterables.

Comment: Thanks you for bringing my attention to the zip function, really neat

Answer (score 0):

Using what @Graipher said and some other things I found my new solution is:

```
split_join = lambda t:''.join(sum(zip(*[s.ljust(len(max(t,key=len))) for s in t]),())).replace(' ','')
```

If I find any better way I will update this code